# Why, while using useEffect() and .then() in Redux, I get an Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: redux, oauth, oauth-2.0, react-redux, react-hooks

using Redux and am now straggling with a signin and signout button while using oauth.

When I press on the button to logIn, the popup window appears and I can choose an account. But in the meantime the webpage throws an error.

[image]

I got the following error as stated in the title:
Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
I am using hooks, in this case useEffect().then() to fetch the data.

[image]

1) Why?

2) Also do not know, why I am getting a warning: The 'onAuthChange' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 35) change on every render. Move it inside the useEffect callback. Alternatively, wrap the 'onAuthChange' definition into its own useCallback() Hook  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Here is my code:

GoogleAuth.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { signIn, signOut } from "../actions";

const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;

const GoogleAuth = () => {
    const isSignedIn = useSelector((state) => state.auth.isSignedIn);
    console.log("IsSignedIn useSelector: " + isSignedIn);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const onAuthChange = () => {
        if (isSignedIn) {
            dispatch(signIn());
        } else {
            dispatch(signOut());
        }
    };

    useEffect(
        () => {
            window.gapi.load("client:auth2", () => {
                window.gapi.client
                    .init({
                        clientId: API_KEY,
                        scope: "email"
                    })
                    .then(() => {
                        onAuthChange(window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
                        console.log("isSignedIn.get(): " + window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
                        window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(onAuthChange);
                    });
            });
        },
        [ onAuthChange ]
    );

    const onSignInOnClick = () => {
        dispatch(window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn());
    };

    const onSignOutOnClick = () => {
        dispatch(window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut());
    };

    const renderAuthButton = () => {
        if (isSignedIn === null) {
            return null;
        } else if (isSignedIn) {
            return (
                <button onClick={onSignOutOnClick} className="ui red google button">
                    <i className="google icon" />
                    Sign Out
                </button>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <button onClick={onSignInOnClick} className="ui red google button">
                    <i className="google icon" />
                    Sign In with Google
                </button>
            );
        }
    };

    return <div>{renderAuthButton()}</div>;
};

export default GoogleAuth;
```

reducer/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import authReducer from "./authReducer";

export default combineReducers({
    auth: authReducer
});
```

reducers/authReducer.js

```
import { SIGN_IN, SIGN_OUT } from "../actions/types";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    isSignedIn: null
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SIGN_IN:
            return { ...state, isSignedIn: true };
        case SIGN_OUT:
            return { ...state, isSignedIn: false };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

actions/index.js

```
import { SIGN_IN, SIGN_OUT } from "./types";

export const signIn = () => {
    return {
        type: SIGN_IN
    };
};

export const signOut = () => {
    return {
        type: SIGN_OUT
    };
};
```

types.js

```
export const SIGN_IN = "SIGN_IN";
export const SIGN_OUT = "SIGN_OUT";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of the first error is that, inside both `onSignInOnClick` and `onSignInOnClick`, `dispatch()` receives a `Promise` (since `window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn()` returns a `Promise`).
There are different solution to handle effects in redux, the simplest are [redux promise](https://github.com/redux-utilities/redux-promise) or [redux thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk).
Otherwise you can dispatch the `{ type: SIGN_IN }` action, and write a [custom middleware](https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware) to handle it.

The reason of the second error, is that the onAuthChange is redefined on every render, as you can see here:

```js
const f = () => () => 42
f() === f() // output: false
```

Here's a possible solution to fix the warning:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const onAuthChange = () => {
    if (isSignedIn) {
      dispatch(signIn())
    } else {
      dispatch(signOut())
    }
  }

  window.gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
    window.gapi.client
      .init({
        clientId: API_KEY,
        scope: 'email',
      })
      .then(() => {
        onAuthChange(window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get())
        console.log(
          'isSignedIn.get(): ' +
            window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get(),
        )
        window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(onAuthChange)
      })
  })
}, [isSignedIn])
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It really helped with the onAuthChange inside the useEffect. Am just wondering, why I need a middleware like thunk to get the app working or is it possible to omit useEffect in this case?

Comment: You can either use React primitives (hooks) to handle effects and state management, or different frameworks like redux.
Unless you really have a reason of using redux, I'd suggest you not to use it in the first place;
You can just use:
[isSignedIn, setIsSignedIn] = useState(false)
You only need useEffect if you want to sync an effect with some variable in the scope, but it is totally fine to do it in a callback, e.g.:
<button onClick={() => window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut()}>Sign out</button>